# best practices for keeping html canvas styling in sync with css stylesheet classes/variables

Tags: css, html5-canvas

I have a site which makes heavy use of html5 canvas (actually createjs/easeljs).  While canvas supports css-compatible strings for property values such as font or color, I'm not aware of any way to specify these values in one place so that they can be shared between the css and canvas code.

It would seem that I need to duplicate my efforts and create a styles_common.css and styles_common.js, and manually keep them in sync.

Does anyone know of a good way to avoid such duplication? I'm not currently using a css pre-processor such as scss. I *hoping* that a perhaps a css processor could import a .js file and substitute values, but I'm open to any solution which isn't hackish.  Otherwise, I suppose I'm stuck duplicating my efforts.

Thanks in advance,

-Scott

Comment: So what's wrong with using preprocessor?

Comment: @Justinas Nothing.  I'm just not sure if a pre-processor can do what I want - importing values from a .js file and performing substitutions

Comment: As `CanvasRenderingContext2D.font` is the only canvas context interface property that uses the same format as a CSS font specifier I see no way to avoid code to convert between 2D context properties and CSS. Note that *"color"* AKA `fillStyle`and `strokeStyle` can accept not just strings but object such as gradients and patterns which are not CSS style specifier strings.